# How i can load data from sql server to office 365 list with ssis

Tags: office-365, sql-server-2012

Please help. OData connection load data **from Office 365** to sql server. How i can load data **from sql server** to office 365 list with ssis?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could create a C# custom code activity in the SSIS package that uses Client Side Object Model (CSOM) to upload data to a list in SharePoint Online. It invovles quite a bit of coding though. I do not know if there is an easier/faster way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the SQL Integration service component available at Codeplex.

> This sample demonstrates how to get data into and out of SharePoint
>   lists by using custom source and destination adapters written in C#
>   3.0. Use this sample to learn more about:

[SharePoint List Source and Destination](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652)